# jQuery duration method

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Currently I am working on an plugin for jQuery. In some jQuery functions you can pass an duration (e.g. `'500ms'`, `'1s'`, `'fast'`) parameter in.

I suppose there is a function within jQuery which pares that value and returns a value in ms? (so `1s` would return `1000` or something).

Which method would this be, and is it possible to use this in my own plugin? So I can fire an callback after `'1s'` or `'fast'` like some other methods as animate currently does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery). There you can see that [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) calls a method [`jQuery.speed`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/effects.js#L354) which uses [`jQuery.fx.speeds`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/effects.js#L597):

```
speeds: {
    slow: 600,
    fast: 200,
    // Default speed
    _default: 400
},
```

`jQuery.speed` seems to be useful in this regard, though I don't see any code which converts `'1s'` into `1000`. Are you sure jQuery is doing this?

Answer (score 2):

let's take a look at jquery source :

```
speeds: {
    slow: 600,
    fast: 200,
    // Default speed
    _default: 400
},
```

So, how about slow fadeOut ? let's take a peek into the source again. It looks like 'fadeOut' is just a shortcut for custom animation. There is a nice generic block of logic that jQuery re-uses for that purpose. There's no point in pasting the whole source in here :) you can easily go to your project a see for your self.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this very easily on your own

```
function ms(s){
  return parseInt(s) *1000;
}

alert(ms("20s"));  #=> 20000
```

Aside from that, using `1000` compared to `'1s'` is hardly an inconvenience.  The integer has additional benefits as it's easier to modify in a programmatic way using simple arithmetic.